# Execution order of Promises in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, event-loop

I executed following code with Node.js v10.15.0

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log('A'))
  .then(() => console.log('B'))
  .then(() => console.log('C'))

setImmediate(() => console.log('IMMEDIATE'))

Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log('D'))
  .then(() => console.log('E'))
  .then(() => console.log('F'))
```

As there is no asynchronous code involved in the fullfilled functions i expected following output

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
IMMEDIATE
```

but i got...

```
A
D
B
E
C
F
IMMEDIATE
```

As far as i understand the situation, the `setImmediate()` call shows us, that none `console.log()` call gets deffered to the next Event Loop iteration. But, why is the order of `console.log()` calls mixed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the `setImmediate()` call shows us, that no `console.log()` calls get deferred to the next Event Loop iteration

Actually they do - remember that promise `then` callbacks are *always* asynchronous.

They just do get run on a different phase of the event loop, they get queued on different task queues. For NodeJS specifically, see the article https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/ for details.

> I expected following output

Don't assume anything about independent promise chains. All you can and should expect is that `B` comes after `A`, `C` comes after `B`, and in the other chain that `E` comes after `D` and `F` after `E`. They are allowed to be interleaved arbitrarily<sup>1</sup> - if you want to ensure order, chain the promises to each other using `then`.

<sub>1: the spec details how the queuing of promise tasks works so that it is consistent between different engine implementations, but those details should be considered irrelevant.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There are two `Promise.resolve()...` promise chains that are executed in parallel.

```
A
D
B
E
C
F
```

is the expected order for them.

In order to execute them in series, it should be:

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log('A'))
  .then(() => console.log('B'))
  .then(() => console.log('C'))
  .then(() => Promise.resolve()) // no-op
  .then(() => console.log('D'))
  .then(() => console.log('E'))
  .then(() => console.log('F'))
```